# How do I get MVC to automatically create a DropDownList in my View using Code First when I have a foreign key defined in my model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, foreign-key-relationship

I have a View that is strongly typed to the model RawValues.  In this view, I want to have a DropDownList that contains a list of Capsules (which are defined in a different model, the Capsule model).  I want to bind the Capsule selected to the CapsuleFk property in my RawValues model.

I'm trying to figure out how I can get a DropDownList (@Html.DropDownListFor) containing my different Capsules to automatically generate onto my View when I scaffold my RawValues Model.  The items in my DropDownList are going to come from the Capsule table, which contains 4 records.  Below, you'll see how I set a `ForeignKey` attribute to my `public int? CapsuleFk` property.  Here's the model I am displaying on my View, and below this one you'll see the Capsule model:

```
namespace CapWorx.QuikCap.Models
{
    public class RawValues
    {
        [Key]
        public int Pk { get; set; }

        public int? FillerFk { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("FillerFk")]
        public virtual Filler Filler { get; set; }

        public int? CapsuleFk { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CapsuleFk")]
        public virtual Capsule Capsule { get; set; }

        public int Active1 { get; set; }
        public int Active2 { get; set; }
        public int Active3 { get; set; }
        public int Active4 { get; set; }
        public int Active5 { get; set; }
        public int KeyActive { get; set; }
        public int KeyActivePackStat { get; set; }
        public bool E4M { get; set; }
        public bool K100M { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the Capsule model:

```
namespace CapWorx.QuikCap.Models
{
    public class Capsule
    {
        [Key]
        public int Pk { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I hope there's something obvious I'm not doing correct.  When I run my app, it automatically creates my SQL database in my local environment (as expected).  Here's a screenshot of my Foreign Key Relationships straight from SQL Server Management Studio, which appears to be correct.  Notice how my Foreign Key base table is correct (RawValues), and my Primary Key base table is also correct (Capsule):

[image]

Can you please help me in determining what I'm doing wrong so that I can create a DropDownList on my RawValues View that contains a list of Capsules which I can then bind the capsule selected to the CapsuleFk property in my RawValues model?

Thanks!

Comment: you can create an editor template to achieve that

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into common problems that arise when you try to bind a Business or Data object directly to a View. It is a MUUUUCH cleaner solution to create a "ViewModel" that your View binds to, and this ViewModel will contain everything the View needs for its UI.

Here's a pattern I use. First, the ViewModel:

```
public class RawValuesEditingViewModel
{
    // Your primary ID
    public int Pk { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? SelectedCapsulePk { get; set; }

    // Other basic fields as needed for editing on this screen
    public int Active1 { get; set; }
    public int Active2 { get; set; }
    public int Active3 { get; set; }
    public int Active4 { get; set; }
    public int Active5 { get; set; }
    public int KeyActive { get; set; }
    // blah blah blah....

    // Use this as the source for your Dropdown List for the capsule choice
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CapsulesToSelectFrom
    {
        get
        {
            return from cap in DatabaseRepository.GetAllCapsules() // or some kind of Repo here.
                   select new SelectListItem {
                       Text = cap.Name,
                       Value = cap.Pk.ToString(),
                       Selected = (cap.Pk == this.SelectedCapsulePk), 
                   };
        }
    }

    public RawValuesEditingViewModel()
    {
        // This constructor is parameter-less because the MVC model binder needs it this way to bind on post back.
        // You can alter this behavior, but it gets hairy.
    }

    // Call this method from your Controller to populate the ViewModel fields. 
    public void LoadModelFieldsFromDataObject(int pkToLoadFrom)
    {
        // get the underlying database object, from EF in your case.
        var rawValuesObj = DatabaseRepository.GetRawValueObjectById(pkToLoadFrom);

        // Map your RawValues data object fields to the RawValuesEditingViewModel fields as needed.
        // Only map the fields you want to present for editing.
        // Check out "AutoMapper" if you are tired of writing this kind of code :)
        this.Pk = rawValuesObj.Pk;
        this.SelectedCapsulePk = rawValuesObj.CapsuleFk; 
        // etc etc etc
    }

    public void ExecuteRawValuesUpdate(int pk)
    {
        // code to persist back to database goes here.
        // probably you will re-fetch the database object, update its fields from this ViewModels fields, then persist it back thru EF.
    }
}
```

And you'll have a database repository class that does the work of fetching those EF entities for you via some clean methods:

```
public static class DatabaseRepository
{
    public static List<Capsule> GetAllCapsules()
    {
        // your EF calls/whatever go here.
    }

    public static RawValues GetRawValueObjectById(int pk)
    {
        // your EF calls/whatever go here.
    }
}
```

Not sure how you are deciding to pass along the ID of the "RawValues" entity you care about, but here's a pair of controller actions where it comes through a QueryString:

```
public ActionResult RawValues(int pk) 
{
    var rawValuesVM = new ViewModels.RawValuesEditingViewModel();
    try
    {
        rawValuesVM.LoadModelFieldsFromDataObject(pk);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // however you wish to handle a bad lookup
    }
    return View(rawValuesVM);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RawValues(ViewModels.RawValuesEditingViewModel rawValuesVM, int pk)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            rawValuesVM.ExecuteRawValuesUpdate(pk);
            // Redirect or something here.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex);
        }
    }
    return View(rawValuesVM);
}
```

Finally, your View will be strongly bound to `RawValuesEditingViewModel`, and you will present the normal fields, and for the drop down for the selected Capsule, it will look like this:

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(mode => model.SelectedCapsulePk, Model.CapsulesToSelectFrom)
```